# Question about Milvus vector database's search operation

Tags: image, vector, artificial-intelligence

Does Milvus search operation only returns primary_ids and distance?

```py
result = collection.search(vectors_to_search, "embeddings", search_params)
```

Answer (score 1):

The search interface for pymilvus==2.0.1 returns a `SearchResult`, which is a collection of multiple `Hit`, and the `Hit` has the `id` & `distance` attributes.

And the search interface also designed a parameter `output_fields` to return more other fields, and it should be already supported by pymilvus==2.0.1. (Although in the code comment it may be marked as not supported yet)

BTW:
Seems the given example code missing one required parameter `limit` also AKA top_k, so the search example code should be like this:

```
result = collection.search(vectors_to_search, "embeddings", search_params, limit=3)
```